# Passing variables to bash script vs setting env variables for the script

Tags: bash, parameter-passing

What's best to pass some environment variables to a script?

```
./script.sh ${A} ${B}
```

or

```
A=${A} B={$B} ./script.sh
```

I've always seen the first one, but a colleague of mine says that the second way is better because you do not have to remember the order of the variables and inside the script when you add a new parameter you do not need to parse it from `$*`.

Apart from making the script call a bit longer, there is any contraindication to do the latter?

I do not want to use `export` (because every script will have access to the env variables) nor to use `.` before invoking the script (I want to make available to the script only a subset of the variables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using positional parameters is okay when you have a small limited amount of parameters.

Once you have a complex script with several parameters named parameters is the preferred way.

There are several methods for named parameters:

1. The method you mentioned:

   A=${A} B={$B} ./script.sh
2. Using **getopt**

[goodcoding getopt](http://www.shelldorado.com/goodcoding/cmdargs.html#getopt) and [posix getopt man](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getopt.html)

3. Using **getopts**

[getopts_tutorial](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial) and [posix getopts man](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/getopts.html#tag_20_54)